# Genesis menu position change

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

Sorry for silly question, I'm pretty new in WordPress and [Genesis](http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis). I want to move Genesis menu above header. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the snippets in Genesis Theme function, in functions.php

```
remove_action('genesis_after_header','genesis_do_nav');
add_action('genesis_before_header','genesis_do_nav');
```